# install ubuntu alongside windows 7 without cd drive

Tags: system-installation

I don't have a CD drive installed in my computer, so I downloaded ubuntu and mounted it with MagicISO, wubi only says that the software is ready to install from a restart (with the CD inside)... since I have no CD drive I have no boot options when I restart the PC... how can I install ubuntu alongside Windows 7?

I remember once (a few months ago) I downloaded a version of ubuntu from ubuntu.com that said that it could be installed from windows, and I did installed ubuntu from a some kind of windows installer application and it was all fine, for some reason I uninstalled it and now I cannot find the way to do it again

How can I achive this?

thank you in advance

Comment: You can install from USB flash memory stick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create live USB pen using [Live USB Creator](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/en/download) Download it after, run it from windows, plug your USB Drive and, select already u have downloaded Ubuntu ISO file and then create Live USD, after everything, in CMOUS setting select boot device property to USB drive and login into live user, after you can install it

Comment: ok, I will try that, thank you for the info, also... am I gonna be able to install ubuntu without touching my current windows and hard disk partition? is it safe to do it? more precisely my files and information is not gonna be deleted right?

Comment: Don't install ubuntu for your windows partition,crate another partition to install ubuntu

Comment: Thank you.. it all helped, now I have Ubuntu installed and running smoothly!